# Python - Exhaust map of multiple iterables

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterable

```
a=['1','2','3']
```

`map(int,a)` can be exhausted using list to yield output:

```
list(map(int,a))
```

output: `1,2,3`

---

```
a=['1','2','3']
b=['1','2']
```

How do I exhaust the following:

```
map(int,a,b)
```

Comment: What "exhaust" means? You mean `a=iter([1,2,3])` ?

Comment: In this case I use it as a term to mean the production of output which isn't <map object at 0x00FB7EB0>

Comment: Ah I didn't know that `map` returns `iterable` in Python ver 3.x. Because `map` returns `list` in Python ver 2.7. I got why you use "Exhaust".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert each of the lists to a list of integers, you can do

```
a, b = ['1','2','3'], ['1','2']
print(list(map(lambda x: map(int,x), [a, b])))
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

which can be assigned to `a` and `b` back, like this

```
a, b = map(lambda x: map(int,x), [a, b])
```

If you want to chain the elements, you can use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), like this

```
from itertools import chain
print(list(map(int, chain(a,b))))
# [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

**Edit:** if you want to pass more than iterable as arguments, then the function also has to accept that many number of parameters. For example,

```
a, b = [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]
print(list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b)))
# [2, 4, 6]
```

If we are passing three iterables, the function has to accept three parameters,

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]
print(list(map(lambda x, y, z: x + y + z, a, b, c)))
# [3, 6, 9]
```

If the iterables are not of the same size, then the length of the least sized iterable will be taken in to consideration. So

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]
print(list(map(lambda x, y, z: x + y + z, a, b, c)))
# [3, 6]
```

Comment: In both cases this seems to make the second argument of map an interable list.  I was trying to understand the how to exhaust the form map(int,iterable1,iterable2,...)

Comment: @Robert What is your expected output?

Comment: I was reading the Python 3 docs and got to "If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted."  I suppose I was expecting 1,2 or two sets 1,2 but I didn't know what form it would come in so I asked the exhaust question to reveal the answer.

Comment: @Robert: the 2nd argument for `int` is the base. So you could do `list(map(int, '19F', [2,10,16]))` to get `[1, 9, 15]`.

Comment: Another way to ask the question may be:  What is an example of map, with multiple iterables, showing the output.